# What is the opposite of "intensifier?"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, antonyms, linguistics

Adverbs, adverbial phrases, or devices of any sort that are used to add force or emphasis to the meaning are called "intensifiers." I wonder if there is a name for phrases that caste some doubt on the accuracy of a given statement, or lessen its force. Anything that gives that effect of "take what I am saying (or what's being said) with a grain of salt"

The examples I have in mind are: "I guess", "I think," "methinketh," ect. when used at the end of a sentence.

Thank you

**P.S:** I should add that I know the phrases "speech fillers" or "speech disfluency." They do not capture the sense I have explained above, because they usually result from too much thinking during speech, an uneasy flow of ideas, lack of confidence or lack of fluency. And this is not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Technically, the opposite of an intensifier is a qualifier, which is used to downplay something to an extent. Both intensifiers and qualifiers are known as modifiers.

Comment: These are hedges. But notice that 'intensifiers' usually emphasise the fact (My hands are really cold), not the conviction that the statement is true (My hands are cold ... _really!_ )

Comment: I would imagine that the counterpart of an _intensifier_ is either a _diminisher_ or a _diluter_.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 100 percent sure the word you're looking for is **uncertainty**.

As I stated in my original comment above, the opposite of an intensifier is a qualifier, which is used to downplay something to an extent. Both intensifiers and qualifiers are known as modifiers. What you are looking for is most definitely a type of qualifier, but this term is still a little too vague for your needs.

*Uncertainties*, though, are a very specific type of qualifier in that they express some level of doubt in an idea. Commonly used uncertainties usually express only a small amount of doubt.

> Example:
>   I'm almost 100 percent sure the word you're looking for is **uncertainty**.

Recognize this sentence? I used the word *almost* here because I have a tiny bit of doubt in my answer (read: *very* tiny). Other uncertainties people commonly use are *possibly*, *maybe*, *seems*, and *might/may*.

Answer (score 1):

In the modality sense, conceding a doubt by the speaker about the accuracy of a statement, this type of hedging is known as using a **downtoner**.

According to [LearningEnglish: Grammar](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/amplifiers-downtoners/3714862.html) [adjusted and amplified below], even as uncommon a word as *downtoner* has confusingly different senses:

> **What are downtoners?**
>
> Other kinds of adverbs act as downtoners. Downtoners are the opposite
> of amplifiers. They reduce the force of a statement or express doubt.
> In other words, they set the tone of a statement. You can remember the
> term 'downtoner' by thinking about what it does: toning down a
> statement.
>
> Downtoners have three common functions:
>
> - (a) reducing intensity
> - (b) expressing doubt
> - (c) showing [acknowledging] imprecision.
>
> Common downtoners in conversational English are *pretty*, [*quite*],
> *maybe*, [*possibly*] and *probably*, say Conrad and Biber.
>
> How can you use downtoners to change the meaning of the statement?
>
> Take the example: *This food is good*.
>
> If you wanted to reduce the intensity of your statement, you could
> say:
>
> (a1) *This food is pretty good.* [The adjective-modifier
> (traditionally a grading adverb) is a downtoner, though this type of
> sentence is commonly intended as understatement. 'Reasonably' is more
> obviously downtoning.]
>
> You could show doubt, even raise questions, by saying:
>
> (b1/2) *This is possibly/probably the best food I've ever had.* [Here,
> the downtoner is a modal adverb, an attempt to convey how likely the
> speaker considers the statement to be. An introductory 'If I'm not mistaken' is another common downtoner showing a measure of doubt.]
>
> [We can signal imprecision in a statement like this:
>
> (c1) *Its age must be pretty/fairly/reasonably close to 1000 years.*
> Here, the downtoner is again an adjective-modifier, contrasting with
> the intensifier 'very' in the more confident claim *Its age must be
> very close to 1000 years.*]
>
> These statements express someone’s opinion about the food. But they
> are not as strong as sentences that use amplifiers [/intensifiers]. In
> other words, saying "This food is pretty good" is not as forceful as
> saying, "This food is really good."